# Django custom serializer response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way of getting django API response as

```
{"1":"country1", "2":"country2"}
```

instead of

```
[{"id":1,"country":"country1"},{"id":2,"country":"country2"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you need simple convert your data:

```
src = [{"id":1,"country":"country1"},{"id":2,"country":"country2"}]
result = dict([(data.get('id'), data.get('country')) for data in src ])
```